# When should I use 'Cheer!', 'Cheers!'?

Tags: meaning

May be it's simple but I'm stuck.

I'm using "Cheers!" for a toast or valediction on any internet forums. When I'm writing "Cheers!" I want say 'Thanks for the communication! Goodbye!' Can I use "Cheer!" for the same? Or does "Cheer!" have a different meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question.

I think 'Cheer' on its own does not stand as an expression. You need to have a phrase.

> I cheered up when she arrived 
>   To cheer her up, I took her on a long drive

On the other hand, if you want to express your 'joy' the way you explained, **in a single word**, it's *Cheers!*

However, you can use multiple 'cheers' to augment your expression! However, it then becomes [an idiom.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cheer)

> *'Three cheers for the winners'*